# Firebase Authentication not working with html form element

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I'm following the Firebase examples that uses web authentication, and I'm not able to login if I use the textboxes and buttons inside a html form element.

Here is the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="app">
        <input type="email" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password">
        <button id="btnLogin">Login</button>
        <button id="btnSignUp">SignUp</button>
        <button id="btnLogout">Logout</button>
</form>

    </body>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

And the js:

```js
(function() {

    // Initialize Firebase
    const config = {
      apiKey: "MyData",
      authDomain: "MyData",
      databaseURL: "MyData",
      projectId: "MyData",
      storageBucket: "MyData",
      messagingSenderId: "MyData"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    const txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
    const btnLogin = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
    const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');
    const btnLogout = document.getElementById('btnLogout');

    btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const email = txtEmail.value;
        const pass = txtPassword.value;
        const auth = firebase.auth();

        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

    });

    btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const email = txtEmail.value;
        const pass = txtPassword.value;
        const auth = firebase.auth();

        const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);

        promise
        .catch(e => console.log(e.message));

    });

    btnLogout.addEventListener('click', e => {
        firebase.auth().signOut();
    });

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
        if(firebaseUser){
            console.log(firebaseUser);
            btnLogout.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            console.log('not logged in');
            btnLogout.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });


}());
```

When I try to login, the console log rises the following message:

*"It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.
For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):
https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-.js"*

**If I move the inputs and buttons outside the form element, the login works perfectly.**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case best thing is to use firebase UI with CDN instead of npm and bower

No worries and no confusion, no errors (I mean less depends on our skill)

1. Add Firebase Authentication to your web application.

Include FirebaseUI via CDN:

Include the following script and CSS file in the  tag of your page, below the initialization snippet:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.5.1/firebaseui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.5.1/firebaseui.css" />
```

2. In the Firebase console, open the Authentication section and enable email and password authentication.

   ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
     signInOptions: [
       firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
     ],
     // Other config options...
   });
3. Other Providers:

   ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
     signInOptions: [
       // List of OAuth providers supported.
       firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
       firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
       firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
       firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
     ],
     // Other config options...
   });

For more info, please follow this link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Could you please be more specific with the different steps? Sorry I'm just starting with firebase. In step 1 I only need to include script and css to my html?  I don't understand where to include the "ui.start..." in step 2. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome, and are you going solve the same or will go Firebase UI CDN integration

Comment: Sorry I'm just starting with firebase. In step 1 I only need to include script and css to my html? I don't understand where to include the "ui.start..." in step 2. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes exactly but it should be in head tag

Comment: ui.start.. should be written in java script

Comment: Thanks, I could make it work, but I would need a custom login/signup form using bootstrap. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, should follow the same procedure in firebase documentation without UI. I’ll help you to do that. If you upvote this answer and make it correct answer that would be helpful many people

Comment: Great if you could help me, I followed the firebase documentation procedure but didn't work.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that the console also returns the following message when using the form element: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred." As soon as I move the input and button elements outside the form I can login.

Comment: Can you share me the more details that how you are getting that error

Comment: I posted an answer explaining better the issue.

Comment: Yes, got it so did get the solution

Comment: No, because I need to use the form element.

Comment: What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this index.html file, this way I can login perfectly, because I commented the form element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- <form id="app"> -->
        <input type="email" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password">
        <button id="btnLogin">Login</button>
        <button id="btnSignUp">SignUp</button>
        <button id="btnLogout">Logout</button>
   <!-- </form> -->

    </body>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="app">
        <input type="email" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password">
        <button id="btnLogin">Login</button>
        <button id="btnSignUp">SignUp</button>
        <button id="btnLogout">Logout</button>
</form>

    </body>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

But using the html like the one I posted initially (using form element) rises the following error to the console:

*"A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."*

Comment: What is inside in app.js

Comment: Look at first post, I included the app.js after html